# Install applications on Hyper V Server

Tags: backup, hyper-v, installation, application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Is it possible to install applications on either Hyper V 2008 or 2012? I don't mean installing applications on child VMs, I mean installing applications on Hyper V server itself. We'd like to install some backup software on a Hyper V machine, but I fear without explorer running on the Hyper V server it's not going to work. Anyone been down this road before?

Comment: Sorry, your question is mostly a licensing issue, even if you didn't realize it. Getting licensing information for relative strangers on the Internet is discouraged, and we automatically close such questions as a duplicate of the one listed. It covers some of the additional reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though this is largely a licensing issue, not a technical one. Hyper-V Server is essentially Windows Server Enterprise Edition Core, with different licensing. There are a few other minor differences. The big differences are:

1. You may only use Hyper-V Server to:

   - provide hardware virtualization services, and/or
   - run software to manage and service operating system environments on the licensed server.
2. Cost, Hyper-V Server is free.

For all the details, see the [Hyper-V Server License](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=497).

I can not attest to the Backup software you intend to use, but I can say that there are several options that will work. Most backup agents have a minimal user interface anyway, so the lack of a GUI doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, decent server management software does not assumea shell. You know, server core also has no UI.